# MySQL Left Join with latest record

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

Given two tables A and B, I want all the records from A where A.Param = "X". I also want a LEFT JOIN on B where B contains records of trials by various A.Ids for various experiments m, n, o...

The records on B have a time stamp as B.TrialTime (DateTime). As the design goes, there can be multiple trials for the same experiment by the same A.Id in B and for the purposes of the LEFT JOIN I need only the latest trial. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Experiment, B.Response, B.Evaluation, MAX(B.TrialTime) FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.UserID = A.ID
WHERE A.Param = "X" GROUP BY concat(B.UserID, B.Experiment)
```

The problem is, it no longer acts as a LEFT JOIN, i.e. I am not getting all the users from A, even if they don't have any record in B, which is what I need. Any help?

Comment: please post your related table structures' code (`create table code`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the specifics of your tables, the problem you face is knowing "the most recent" trial (in table B)

In many rdbms one can use ROW_NUMBER() to solve this problem, but as yet MySQL does not supply that useful function. So you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT
        a.*
      , b.*
FROM A
        LEFT JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                        bb.*
                FROM B bb
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                                SELECT
                                        UserID
                                      , MAX(TrialTime) MostRecent
                                FROM B
                                GROUP BY B.UserID
                        ) bmax ON bb.UserID = bmax.UserID
                                AND bb.TrialTime = bmax.MostRecent
        ) b ON B.UserID = A.ID
```

Basically it isn't possible to get the MAX() of some columns, and all the other column values "from that row", at the same time. You need to get the MAX(TrialTime) then join back to the same table to get the appropriate rows.

For comparison, if row_number() was available, this is how it might be done:

```
SELECT
        a.*
      , b.*
FROM A
        LEFT JOIN
        (
                SELECT
                        bb.*
                      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bb.userid 
                                           ORDER BY bb.TrialTime DESC) AS rn
                FROM B bb
        ) b ON B.UserID = A.ID
                AND b.rn = 1
```

---

By the way, there isn't any specific reason given for using a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN. If you want rows from A that have NO joined data in B, then you would need an outer join, otherwise you should use an INNER JOIN for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't realized that the other column values didn't correspond to the Max(TrialTime) record. The Inner Join solution worked for me.